# htaccess redirect rule needed for incorrect subdirectories with wildcards

Tags: regex, .htaccess, wildcard, subdirectory

I need help writing an htaccess redirect or rewrite rule (mod_rewrite.c) to handle the following situation:

`http://www.mysite.com/archive/[YEAR]/archive/[YEAR]/[CORRECT-PATH]`

should redirect to:

`http://www.mysite.com/archive/[YEAR]/[PATH]`

Basically, there are some externals links that have incorrectly doubled-up on the `/archive/[YEAR]/` part of the path, where there should only be one instance. I have a sub-directory for each year (/archive/2011, /archive/2012, etc.) - those year directories are the roots of separate Drupal installations - each with their own .htaccess file (which is tripping me up).

The `[CORRECT-PATH]` bit is usually an alias to a Drupal page, for example:

`http://www.mysite.com/archive/2012/winners/all`

I'm not so good with wildcard and matching syntaxes - any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rules to your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?archive/([0-9]{4})/archive/\1/(.*)$ /archive/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

This checks that the year is duplicated, for any 4 digit year. so:

1. `http://www.mysite.com/archive/1234/archive/2345/blah/blah` does nothing
2. `http://www.mysite.com/archive/2345/archive/2345/blah/blah` gets redirected to
   `http://www.mysite.com/archive/2345/blah/blah`
3. `http://www.mysite.com/archive/1234/blah/blah` does nothing.

---

After looking at your problem again, you're going to need to add rules to each of your `/archive/[YEAR]` directories:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /archive/2011/
RewriteRule ^archive/[0-9]{4}/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

And change the `RewriteBase` for each of your directories.

Comment: The latter option did it! Thanks. I had tried code similar to the first option here before but it wasn't quite taking, probably because of the lack of a RewriteBase in those sub-directories. Do sub-directories inherit parent directory .htaccess rules if they are missing in their own directory?